# Using multiple TLS protocols gives warning in Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

Properties:

```
server.ssl.enabled-protocols=TLSv1.2,TLSv1.3
```

Output warning:

```
o.apache.tomcat.util.net.SSLHostConfig : The protocol [TLSv1.2] was added to the list of protocols on the SSLHostConfig named [default]. Check if a +/- prefix is missing.
```

*[TLSv1.2] is replaced with [TLSv1.3] depedning on order.*

Any clue how to fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is "just" warning. Tomcat used to use a `,` as the separator but changed to using a `+` and a `-` to indicate to add or remove the protocol. Regardless of the warning it will still work as it should.

See the following comment from the Tomcat source code.

```java
// List of protocol names, separated by ",", "+" or "-".
// Semantics is adding ("+") or removing ("-") from left
// to right, starting with an empty protocol set.
// Tokens are individual protocol names or "all" for a
// default set of supported protocols.
// Separator "," is only kept for compatibility and has the
// same semantics as "+", except that it warns about a potentially
// missing "+" or "-".
```

Spring Boot will call the `setProtocols` of the [`SSLHostConfig`](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-9.0-doc/config/http.html#SSL_Support_-_SSLHostConfig) using a single string, it will concat the array of `String` in `ServerProperties` using a `,`. Hence a warning will be emitted by Tomcat.

You can replace the `,` with a `+` in your configuration to prevent the warning.